# How to find listeners to RaisePropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I have a class `NoteCompositeViewModel` whereby one of its methods does a `RaisePropertyChanged(string.Empty)`. How can I find who is listening to this event when it is raised by this method? I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with Resharper.

I'm trying to debug the application and apparently this event is causing other classes to run their respective methods but I need to know which methods, so that I can put a breakpoint in them.

Comment: Why don't you just put a breakpoint on the raising of "PropertyChanged", and then hit F11 to step into the invocation?

Comment: The event will be a multicast event, at the call to RaisePropertyChanged, you won't know who's "subscribed".  You'll have to breakout the multicast event, or as @McGarnagle points out, step into each...

Comment: Note also: at runtime you can call "PropertyChanged.GetInvocationList()" to get the bound methods ... not sure how useful that is, though.

Answer (score 1):

As far as debugging, probably the easiest way is to place a breakpoint at this line in the view-model base class:

```
if (PropertyChanged != null)
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
```

Hit F11 or step-into, and you should trace into each method in the invocation list, in sequence.

If you're in the debugger, you can also check "PropertyChanged" in the watch window.  If you expand it enough, you can see the complete list of invocation targets.  Some of these will be due to bindings - you can tell these because the target will be the infrastructure class "System.Windows.Data.WeakPropertyChangedListener".

[image: Invocation list]